# Node.JS backend injection prevention using .replace()

Tags: node.js, security, backend

I'm doing anti injection to my backend code,
Issue: users bypassed my code and injected to html html code (this was private test i didnt recived what they typed to bypass)
My current code is  message:

```js
...
data.message.replace(/</gi, "&lt;").replace(/>/gi, "&gt;").replace(/&/gi, "&amp;")
...
```

As i tested with "&lt;script&gt;console.log('im hacker im injecting smth')&lt;/script&gt; & i love cats!" it works fine and replaces thorough when i put \ or so it can get sometimes bypassed...
is here any way to prevent that fully from bypassing?

I expect from code to prevent any injection

Comment: Just don't try to interpret user input as executable code. Don't try to "fix" it. Or if really needed, just use a proper HTML sanitisation. Do note that the DOM already just does it for you if you do `element.textContent = input` which removes the need to do hacky sanitisation by yourself.